# Patching in unit tests does not work, actual method is being called

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, patch

I have a python file : update_baseline_manifest.py. Now, I am writing unit tests and want to patch read_file and write_file and I have done it like

```
def update_baseline_manifest(baseline_manifest_path, vbf_info_map, logger):
    """ Updates manifest as per the part numbers in the vbfs_map """
    try:
        manifest_contents = read_file(baseline_manifest_path)
        // Do something


        write_file(manifest_contents, baseline_manifest_path)

def read_file(file_path):
    print('called read')
    with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
        return yaml.safe_load(file)


def write_file(contents, file_path):
    print('called write')
    with open(file_path, 'w') as file:
        yaml.dump(contents, file)
```

The test file looks like

```
from a.b.update_baseline_manifest import update_baseline_manifest

def test_update_baseline_manifest(self):
    test_contents = 'sample contents'

    with patch('update_baseline_manifest.read_file', return_value=test_contents) as \
        mock_read, patch('update_baseline_manifest.write_file') as mock_write:
        result = update_baseline_manifest(self.args.baseline_manifest_path,
                                            self.args.vbf_info_map,
                                            self.args.logger)

    mock_read.assert_called_with(self.args.baseline_manifest_path)
    mock_write.assert_called_with(contents_written, self.args.baseline_manifest_path)
    self.assertEqual(result, 0)
```

Now I can see the prints I added so it means the actual function was called and the mocked one wasn't. How do I patch them correctly so my mocked function gets called and not the actual one after importing the file at the top? I read a lot of posts about it but I cant get my head around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide full path of the function you want to mock.
Refer to:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch

```py
    ...
    with patch('a.b.update_baseline_manifest.read_file', return_value=test_contents) as \
mock_read, patch('a.b.update_baseline_manifest.write_file') as mock_write:
    ...
```

Comment: Cheers, I'd be obliged if you marked the answer as the accepted one then.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your code in my system and as @Gameplay says the only problem is the path of the module that you use in the `patch()` instruction.

### The most important modification

I have changed:

```
# YOUR
with patch('update_baseline_manifest.read_file', return_value=test_contents) as mock_read, \
     patch('update_baseline_manifest.write_file') as mock_write:

#+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
# TO MINE: I have added in the patch() instruction the
# path to reach the file update_baseline_manifest.py
#+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
with patch('a.b.update_baseline_manifest.read_file', return_value=test_contents) as mock_read, \
     patch('a.b.update_baseline_manifest.write_file') as mock_write:
```

In fact you patch the objects point by the names `update_baseline_manifest.read_file` and `update_baseline_manifest.write_file` but when your test code invokes the function `update_baseline_manifest` (code under test), this function calls the real objects and **not the mocked objects**.

---

The rest of the answer details the code used to replicate the test in my system.

### Your production code in my system

I have recreated your script `update_baseline_manifest.py` as followed:

```
def update_baseline_manifest(baseline_manifest_path, vbf_info_map, logger):
    """ Updates manifest as per the part numbers in the vbfs_map """
    try:
        manifest_contents = read_file(baseline_manifest_path)
        # Do something
        write_file(manifest_contents, baseline_manifest_path)
        return 0
    except Exception as ex:
        print(str(ex))

def read_file(file_path):
    print('called read')
    with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
        return yaml.safe_load(file)

def write_file(contents, file_path):
    print('called write')
    with open(file_path, 'w') as file:
        yaml.dump(contents, file)
```

I have added only some instructions in the function `update_baseline_manifest`:

- `return 0` to pass your test `self.assertEqual(result, 0)`
- `except Exception as ex:` to complete your `try:` instruction

The file is saved in the path `a/b/update_baseline_manifest.py` where `a` and `b` contains the file `__init__.py`

### Your test code in my system

My test code is the following:

```
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch
from a.b.update_baseline_manifest import update_baseline_manifest

# utility class for not change your test code
class ARGS:
    baseline_manifest_path = "/path/to/manifest"
    vbf_info_map = "vbf info map"
    logger = "logger"

class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    args = ARGS()

    def test_update_baseline_manifest(self):
        test_contents = 'sample contents'
        with patch('a.b.update_baseline_manifest.read_file', return_value=test_contents) as mock_read \
             patch('a.b.update_baseline_manifest.write_file') as mock_write:
            result = update_baseline_manifest(self.args.baseline_manifest_path,
                                                self.args.vbf_info_map,
                                                self.args.logger)

        mock_read.assert_called_with(self.args.baseline_manifest_path)
        #mock_write.assert_called_with(contents_written, self.args.baseline_manifest_path)
        mock_write.assert_called_with(test_contents, self.args.baseline_manifest_path)
        self.assertEqual(result, 0)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

In the test file I have added the following `import`:

```
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch
```

I have also added the (*utility*) `class ARGS` to define the attribute `arg` of `MyTestCase`:

```
class ARGS:
    baseline_manifest_path = "/path/to/manifest"
    vbf_info_map = "vbf info map"
    logger = "logger"
```

I have modified one your test as followed:

```
# your test
#mock_write.assert_called_with(contents_written, self.args.baseline_manifest_path)

# my test
mock_write.assert_called_with(test_contents, self.args.baseline_manifest_path)
```

**The last, but the most important modification** (as I have written at the top of the answer):

> I have changed the path inside the `patch` instructions.

### The output

The output of the execution is:

```
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

OK
```

In the output is not present any printed message so we are sure that the production code is not invoked!

---

[This link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch) is very useful to understand **where to patch**.

Other useful examples are in the following posts:

- [post answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75903433/error-in-the-patch-of-a-function-by-mockers-and-pytest/75917092#75917092) with the same error present in your code.
- [other post answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75145257/why-is-my-function-still-making-api-calls-even-though-i-am-mock-patching-it/75147297#75147297) with the same error present in your code.

Comment: Thank you! Yes it works after updating the path. Updated my asserts as well.