# Error in the patch of a function by mockers and pytest

Tags: python, mocking, pytest, pytest-mock

I am trying to use pytest and mocker to test a python package that I am writing.  This is the outline of my repo (assuming package is called `hoopla`)

```
hoopla
|- library
  |- __init__.py
  |- general
  |- exceptions
  |- bourhaha 
|- tests
  |- __init__.py
  |- test_brouhaha
```

Inside `general.py` I have some functions that can be used via the package and also files inside the package. For example:

- `general.py` contains the function `validate_email_exists()`
- `brouhaha.py` contains a function called `create_username()` that calls the function `validate_email_exists()`.

Inside `test_brouhaha.py` I want to mock the `validate_email_exists()` call when testing the function `create_username()` as it calls out to an external system.
When I try to mock this call using pytest and pytst-mock I get an error saying No Module... (see below).

```
# general.py

def validate_email_exists(email):
  return True
```

```
# bourhaha.py

from .general import validate_email_exists

def create_username(email):
  if not validate_email_exists(email):
    return False
  # create usename
  return True
```

```
# test_bourhaha.py

from library.bourhaha import *

def test_create_username(mocker):
  mock_email_exists = mocker.patch("library.bourhaha.general.validate_email_exists") # causes error
---
  mock_email_exists = mocker.patch("library.general.validate_email_exists") # causes error
  mock_email_exists.return_value = False
  assert create_username("test") # Fails because value of validate_email_exists return True
---
```

In my code I initially mocked with

```
mock_email_exists = mocker.patch("library.brouhaha.general.validate_email_exists")
mock_email_exists.return_value = False
```

And this throws the error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'library.brouhaha.general'; 'library.brouhaha' is not a package
```

When I try

```
mock_email_exists = mocker.patch("library.general.validate_email_exists")
mock_email_exists.return_value = False
```

There is no error however the test fails because the function is returning True

Comment: Perhaps I missed some point, but it's sometimes written `brouhaha`, sometimes `bourhaha`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Where to patch

The problem is in the path used by the `patch()` function. The correct path is:

```
# CORRECT PATCHING
mock_email_exists = mocker.patch("library.bourhaha.validate_email_exists")
```

See [where to patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch) in the documentation to know other details about a correct use of `patch()`.

In your case the file `general.py` defines the function `validate_email_exists`, but the file `bourhaha.py` execute the `import` instruction:

```
from .general import validate_email_exists
```

so it creates a name `validate_email_exists` in its namespace. You have to change the object pointed by this name. With your `patch()` you have changed the object in the place where it is defined.

### Back to your code

In your code you set the `return_value` of `mock_email_exists` to `False`. At this point you have to also change the `assert` instruction because the function `create_username()` return `False` when the function `validate_email_exists()` return `False`.

So the correct test function is:

```
from library.bourhaha import *

def test_create_username(mocker):
    # WATCH to the path = 'library.bourhaha.validate_email_exists'
    mock_email_exists = mocker.patch("library.bourhaha.validate_email_exists")
    mock_email_exists.return_value = False
    # I have change the assert test (assert ---> assert not)
    assert not create_username("test")
```

Your modules `general.py` and `bourhaha.py` are perfect.